# What is the right design to have a spring Entity that is different than what the REST API returns?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Right now, I have an @Entity say Car that has a certain set of attributes. This gets persisted into a database.

Now, in the @RestController, if I want to accept a Car parameter **except for certain properties**, how do I do that? Right now, I am creating a different class called CarInput that is the same as Car minus those properties.

Again, for REST API response, same thing. If I want to return a Car but with a certain field removed. Right now I created CarResponse as a model.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: In an API that follows the REST architecture model you don't focus on types but on representation formats. Usually so called REST APIs use [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) though instead of properly negotiating about the exchanged format. The documentation of the API becomes now the truth and must not change (as well as the API itself) as otherwise clients will break. With a mapping, as suggested by Sean, you should be able to transform your business object back and forth through the supported representations.

Answer (score 2):

I'd make the case that your external representation and your internal storage should hardly ever be identical. Sure, there'll be significant overlap, but your database and your API should be as independent from each other as possible.

I'd say it's a good practice to have separate domain models for the model and view layer (read: two different Car classes, in different packages). You can use a mapping framework like Dozer or [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org) to map back and forth between these different entity types.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So would you recommend that I have different model for REST input and output? For example, I dont want to accept userID as input since it's auto generated by the backend, but I do want to return userID as output.

Comment: What about `code repeated` for model and view layer? it would be a bad practice to have `code repeated`.even using tools automated that breaks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern in POO.

Comment: @erotsppa It seems you expose your `Car` model directly to the client. This is always bad. In general the main premise of a REST API should always be that a server is teaching a client what it can do next. This is similar to a typical Web pages where a server will provide you a form to enter data in and it will usually transfer that data as `www-form-urlencoded` and there mapped back to some internal business object. There are approaches for JSON based forms, such as hal+forms or siren, though they might not be widely accepted yet

Comment: @RomanVottner yes I'm now aware. But that's why I'm asking is it recommended that I create two models (one for database mapping) and (one for accepting input from REST). And then use MapStruct to map between the 2.

Comment: @erotsppa It is for sure preferable to exposing the model directly or using a tailor-made mapping. I.e. I work in the area of EDI for a company that act as a middleman between all those fancy ERP systems, each promoting their own custom format. It is cumbersome to exchange messages between all those systems so we have our own, huge, internal model where we map those format onto ours, process the request according to our model and map the result back to their expected model. this is not trivial though spares a lot of M:N mappings for each type

Comment: @erotsppa but REST especially targets cases where you have a lot of different clients not under your control and you want to keep the freedom to evolve freely in future. If your only client of the API is your Angular/React frontend, spare yourself some effort and avoid trying to be REST compliant (in it's true sense), but avoid calling such an API REST then as [Fielding made it clear when an API can be called REST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)

Comment: @RomanVottner sorry I don't follow, you are adding more confusion. I am going to take this approach: Create two models Car and CarDTO. Car will be mapped to the database fields using Entity. CarDTO will be accepted in my REST call. CarDTO will omit some properties (such as ID). Is this good? Yes/No?

Answer (score 0):

There are two common approaches to such problem.

1. Use [@JsonIgnore](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) on fields/getters that you want to exclude. However, this can lead to annotation hell or generally hard to read code.

```
@JsonIgnore
private String password;
```

2. Create a DTO class that data would be deserialized from or serialized to. What I mean is that when some user makes a POST request with a `car` definition, it would be deserialized by spring to `CarDto` and then parsed by you in the service layer to the `Car` object which you could save to a database. Similarly, `Car` object would be parsed to `CarDto` if the user asks for a data.

```
    @GetMapping("/{userId}")
    UserDto getUser(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        return userService.getUser(userId);
    }

    @PostMapping
    UserDto addUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        return userService.createUser(userDto);
    }
```

This one, on the other hand, could lead to a situation where you sometimes use a Dto and sometimes the class itself. Because of that, consider parsing to/from `CarDto` only in the controller layer (unlike in the example above)

Also it's good to avoid creating two classes in one file. It makes hard to find a desired class afterwards.

Comment: Thats exactly the kind of situation I find myself in. So for the userDto for example it doesn't have the property Id (because its auto generated with @GeneratedValue). So I don't want to accept it for addUser, but I do want to return it with getUser. Does that approach makes sense?

Comment: try `@JsonIgnore(access = Access.READ_ONLY)`
http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.Access.html

Answer (score 0):

You can still avoid of using a DTO class.

- When you post Car object to controller your can control the wanted properties and operate on it.
- For selecting fields to return as the response you can use json views.

Entity :

```
public Car {
  private String color;

  @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
  private Integer weight;

  // getters, setters
}
```

Controller :

```
@RestController
public CarController
  @Autowired
  private CarRepository carRepository;

  @GetMapping("/{id}")
  @JsonView(View.Public.class)
  public Book get(@PathVariable Long id){
     return carRepository.findOne(id);
  }

  @PostMapping
  public Book update(@RequestBody Car car) {
    // only properties we want to update
    if(car.getColor() != null) {
      // save in database or other operations
    }
  }
}
```

View :

```
public class Views {
    public static class Public {
    }
}
```

This way the controller's method "get" will send to client only "weight" property and "update" method will operate only on selected properties.